# Fusion category and induction matrix to its Drinfeld center: combinatorial properties

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, subfactors, fusion-categories, drinfeld-center

This question is inspired by [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0129167X17500094) of Scott Morrison and Kevin Walker.

Consider a fusion category $\mathcal{C}$ of rank $r$, and its Drinfeld center $Z(\mathcal{C})$ of rank $s$.
Let $N_i = (n_{ij}^k)$, $1 \le i \le r $, be the $r\times r$ fusion matrices of $\mathcal{C}$.
Let $I_{\mathcal{C}} = (m_{kl})$ be the $r \times s$ matrix for the induction from $\mathcal{C}$ to $Z(\mathcal{C})$.

Consider $c(\mathcal{C},k,a) = card(\{ (i,j) \ | \ n_{ij}^k = a \})$ and $c(I_{\mathcal{C}},k,a) = card(\{ l \ | \ m_{kl} = a \})$.

**Question 1**: Is the following equality true for $\mathcal{C} = Rep(G)$ with $G$ a finite group, and $a>0$? $$c(\mathcal{C},k,a) = c(I_{\mathcal{C}},k,a)$$

It is checked for $G = C_2, C_3, S_3, D_5, A_5$. We also found *formal* solutions for $I_{\mathcal{C}}$ with the above equality for $G= A_4, D_4, Q_8$. So is for the Hopf ${\rm C^*}$-algebras of dimensions $8$ and $12$. Then:

**Question 2**: It is also true for $\mathcal{C} = Rep(\mathbb{A})$ with $\mathbb{A}$ a (finite dimensional) Hopf ${\rm C^*}$-algebra?

Note that it is false for the Extended-Haagerup fusion categories $EH_1$ and $EH_2$.

---

We can check Q1 directly for $G=S_3$ and $A_5$ by observing the matrices below.

For $\mathcal{C} = Rep(S_3)$, the fusion matrices are $$ \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{matrix} \right), 
\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{matrix} \right), 
\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 
\end{matrix} \right), $$ and the induction matrix is

$$ 
\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix} \right). $$

For $\mathcal{C} = Rep(A_5)$, the fusion matrices are

$$ 
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1 \end{smallmatrix} \right), 
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1&0&0&0\\1&1&0&0&1\\0&0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1&1 \end{smallmatrix} \right), 
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&1\\1&0&1&0&1\\0&1&0&1&1\\0&1&1&1&1 \end{smallmatrix} \right), 
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&1&1&1\\0&1&0&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1&2 \end{smallmatrix} \right), 
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&1\\0&1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1&2\\1&1&1&2&2 \end{smallmatrix} \right), 
 $$ and the induction matrix is

$$ 
\left(\begin{matrix}
0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0&1 \\
1&1&0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&1&0 \\
1&1&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0 \\
1&1&1&2&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0 \\
2&2&2&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0 
\end{matrix} \right). $$

The above matrices come from personal computation and should be confirmed.

---

Any other combinatorial properties (proved or asked) are welcome. For examples:

**Bonus question 1**: Is it true that rank$(Z(\mathcal{C})) \le $ rank$(\mathcal{C})^2$? If so, is there a better bound?

Let $m_1$ and $m_2$ be the maximal entry of the fusion matrices of $\mathcal{C}$, and of the matrix $I_{\mathcal{C}}$, respectively.

**Bonus question 2**: Is it true that $m_1 \ge m_2$.

BQ1 and BQ2 are checked by all the fusion categories cited above.

Answer (score 2):

BQ1 has the following counter-example (inspired by a discussion with Corey Jones):

For $\mathcal{C} = Rep(D_9)$, the fusion rules are:

$$ \begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0\\
  0&1&0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&1&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&1&0&0\\
  0&0&0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&0&0&0&1\end{smallmatrix} \ , \
\begin{smallmatrix}0&1&0&0&0&0\\
  1&0&0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&1&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&1&0&0\\
  0&0&0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&0&0&0&1\end{smallmatrix} \ , \
 \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&1&0&0&0\\
  0&0&1&0&0&0\\
  1&1&0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&0&1&1&0\\
  0&0&0&1&0&1\\
  0&0&1&0&1&0\end{smallmatrix} \ , \
 \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&1&0&0\\
  0&0&0&1&0&0\\
  0&0&0&1&1&0\\
  1&1&1&0&0&0\\
  0&0&1&0&0&1\\
  0&0&0&0&1&1\end{smallmatrix} \ , \ 
 \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&0&1&0&1\\
  0&0&1&0&0&1\\
  1&1&0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&1&1&0&0\end{smallmatrix} \ , \ 
 \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&0&1&0\\
  0&0&0&0&1&1\\
  0&0&1&1&0&0\\
  1&1&0&1&0&0\end{smallmatrix}   $$
and the induction matrix is:
$$ \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1
\end{smallmatrix}\right) $$
It follows that $44=$ rank$(Z(\mathcal{C})) \not \le$ rank$(\mathcal{C})^2 = 36$.